# Invalid Token - The audience 'empty' is invalid

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following Identity Server 4 configuration on ASP.NET Core 3.1 projects:

```
services
  .AddIdentityServer(y => {
    y.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
    y.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
    y.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
    y.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
  })
  .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
  .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
  .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources())
  .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.ApiResources())
  .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.GetApiScopes())
  .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
  .AddProfileService<ProfileService>()
  .AddAspNetIdentity<User>();
```

The `Config` is the following:

```
public static class Config {

  public static List<ApiResource> ApiResources() {
    return new List<ApiResource> { 
      new ApiResource("api", "API Resource")
    };
  }

  public static List<ApiScope> ApiScopes() {
    return new List<ApiScope> { 
      new ApiScope("api", "API Scope") 
    };
  }

  public static List<IdentityResource> IdentityResources() {
    return new List<IdentityResource> { 
      new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
      new IdentityResources.Profile(),
      new IdentityResources.Email() 
    };
  }   

  public static List<Client> Clients() {
    return new List<Client> { 
      new Client {
        ClientId = "mvc",
        ClientName = "MVC Client",
        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
        ClientSecrets = { new Secret("Secret".Sha256()) }
        AllowedScopes = { 
          IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
          IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile, 
          IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email, 
          IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
          "api"
        }         
      }
    };
  }

}
```

And on the API I have:

```
  services
    .AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, x => {
      x.ApiName = "api";
      x.ApiSecret = "Secret"
      x.Authority = Config.AuthorityUrl;
      x.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
      x.EnableCaching = true;
      x.CacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
    });
```

I called one API endpoint using Insomnia client with OAuth2:

[image]

I was able to get the Access token but when calling the API I got the error:

```
Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience 'empty' is invalid"
```

I checked the Access token using JWT and I got the following:

**Header**

```
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "kid": "A1042705E52832C676596F36BB1898AB",
  "typ": "at+jwt"
}
```

**Payload**

```
{
  "nbf": 1598478410,
  "exp": 1598482010,
  "iss": "https://localhost:5000",
  "client_id": "mvc",
  "jti": "23525FF997FD4D71E13C786A7AD07B5D",
  "iat": 1598478410,
  "scope": [
    "api"
  ]
}
```

The `aud` is missing. But do I need it? After reading the IS4 docs I tried adding:

```
.AddIdentityServer(y => {
  y.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
```

Now the Access token has `aud` field but its value is not `api`. Shouldn't it be?

```
"aud": "https://localhost:5000/resources"
```

When calling the API I now get the error:

```
Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience 'https://localhost:5000/resources' is invalid"
```

I read the docs and IS4 examples but couldn't find a solution.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you need to do is connect the ApiScope with the APIRespource to get api to be the desired scope. The https://localhost:5000/resources aud claim is a generic audience when the scopes and api's are not "connected".

In your API definition you need to do something like in this example (Look at the Scopes property below)

```
var invoiceApi = new ApiResource()
{
    Name = "invoice",   //This is the name of the API
    Description = "This is the invoice Api-resource description",
    Enabled = true,
    DisplayName = "Invoice API Service",
    Scopes = new List<string> { "shop.admin", "shop.employee" },
};
```

See this [link](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html?highlight=emit#authorization-based-on-scopes) for details about the generic resource scope that is ussued.

It says:

> When using the scope-only model, no aud (audience) claim will be added
> to the token, since this concept does not apply. If you need an aud
> claim, you can enable the EmitStaticAudience setting on the options.
> This will emit an aud claim in the issuer_name/resources format. If
> you need more control of the aud claim, use API resources.

You can try to set the **EmitStaticAudience** option to **false**.

You can also ignore the two audiences in the token.

To complement this answer, I write a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic:
[IdentityServer – IdentityResource vs. ApiResource vs. ApiScope](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/02/identityserver-identityresource-vs-apiresource-vs-apiscope/)

Comment: I followed your suggestion and it worked but something strange happens. Now `aud` in the token is:   "aud": [  "api", "https://localhost:5000/resources" ]. Shouldn't  "https://localhost:5000/resources" disappear from `aud` since now api resource and scope are connected?

Comment: updated my answer, hope that makes the answer acceptable. The /resources audience is a new thingy in version 4.x or IdentityServer4

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I just marked as answer. It really help me!

Comment: @ToreNestenius, I wish I could upvote you more :)

Answer (score 0):

```
AddIdentityServer((options) =>
{
    options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
}
```

Should also do the trick if you just want to setup working authentication for demo/training app purposes.

Answer (score 0):

In Startup.cs (.NET 5) or Program.cs (>.NET 5) try to update AddIdentityCore (AddIdentity)

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole<int>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders(); <-- Add this!
```